# Trying to store an image path in a MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I want to store an image path in a `MySql` field. When I add the path the slashes are removed from the path for an unknown reason on `MySql`. Now upon data retrieval I receive the path without the backslash thus the path is invalid. I'm using `C#` and with the path I will store an image in a picture box.

So for example I have this path:

```
C:/Files/Pictures/pic1.jpg
```

On MySql it is appearing like this:

```
C:FilesPicturespic1.jpg
```

Is there any way to keep the slashes on `MySql`?

Comment: I'd need to see your code to help.

Comment: To escape the backslash escape character, use \\.